# How to configure Packer ssh into GCP VM for building image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, packer

I am building GCP image with packer. I created service account of "Compute Instance Admin v1" and "Service Account User". It can successfully create the VM but cannot ssh into the instance to proceed further for the custom image.

Error message

`Build 'googlecompute.custom-image' errored after 2 minutes 20 seconds: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH. This can happen if your username/password are wrong. You may want to double-check your credentials as part of your debugging process. original error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain`

build file source code (packer.pkr.hcl)

```
locals {
  project_id              = "project-id"  
  source_image_family     = "rocky-linux-8"           
  source_image_project_id = ["rocky-linux-cloud"]     
  ssh_username            = "packer"                  
  machine_type            = "e2-medium"              
  zone                    = "us-central1-a"  
}

source "googlecompute" "custom-image" {

  image_name = "custom-image"  # Name of image to be created
  image_description       = "Custom Image 1"    # Description for image to be created
  project_id              = "${local.project_id}"
  source_image_family     = "${local.source_image_family}"
  source_image_project_id = "${local.source_image_project_id}"
  ssh_username            = "${local.ssh_username}"
  machine_type            = "${local.machine_type}"
  zone                    = "${local.zone}"
}

build {
  sources = ["source.googlecompute.custom-image"]

  #
  # Run arbitrary shell script file
  #
  provisioner "shell" {
    execute_command = "sudo su - root -c \"sh {{ .Path }} \""
    script          = "foo.sh"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is associated with Qwiklab. I was using the lab environment provided by Qwiklab for testing packer and GCP.

Once I deployed the same thing on regular GCP project. The packer ran successfully. it is suggested there may be some constraints in the lab environment of Qwiklab.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are having trouble connecting via SSH to the Packer-created instance for your GCP image. If the username and password are incorrect or if the necessary [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) are not granted, this error message indicates that the authentication process failed. Check to see if the Compute Instance Admin v1 and Service Account User roles have the necessary access rights to resolve this issue. In addition, the project's firewall rules may need to be set up to allow incoming SSH connections on the port you're using. You can refer to the official [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding) for more information regarding the configuration of firewall rules. You can also connect to the instance and continue troubleshooting the issue by using the "gcloud compute ssh" command.

Attaching [troubleshooting ssh](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors) for reference.